# C# Regex Match/Replace Large Text File

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a large text file can be up to +500MB) that I need to replace all occurances of a date that occurs in a specific string. I'm using a regex to match the date and that works great. I need to capture the line number, the match and the entire line that the match occurs in. I have that part working, it's the replacement part that I'm struggling with. Ideally I would like to make the match, capture the extra info and do the replacement in one trip through the file. How can I do this efficiently? This is what I'm using to execute the regex.

```
while ((line = InputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Increment for each line read
    x++;

    // Try to match each line against the Regex.
    Match m = reg.Match(line);                    
    if (m.Success) 
    {
        DateTime result;
        if (!(DateTime.TryParse(m.Groups[0].Value, out result)))
        {
            // add it to the DT
            MatchTable.Rows.Add(x, m.Groups[0].Value, line);   
        }
        else if (DateTime.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value).Year <= 1753) // 1753 is the earliest date that can be stored in SQL datetime
        {
            // add it to the DT                       
            MatchTable.Rows.Add(x, m.Groups[0].Value, line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be done with asynchronous read/write? (Not that I know how to do it, just wondering)

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd probably build a second temp file line by modified line, then delete the old file and rename the new one on completion.